# OrientDB OR evaluation

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'd like to take advantage of short circuiting the OR in an Orient's SQL query I'm writing. Does Orient's OR short circuit and does it evaluate its terms from left to right or right to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrientDB WHERE condition evaluation is not completely executed as it's written, so  you cannot rely 100% on OR operations short circuit.

In V 2.2 the execution planner tries to do some simple assumptions and evaluate indexed conditions first, then it will evaluate expressions from left to right.

In next V 3.0 the execution planner is much more complex and can do a complete rewriting of the WHERE condition to make the query more efficient, so you should not rely on short circuit in general